# Google app engine generated ids unique for different entities

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

There are two entities in my Google App Engine data store with Java, Objectify 4, i have a requirement in which the auto generated ids of these two entities should be unique, that is, id from first entity will never have an entry for second entity.

How to make sure that generated ids are not repeated for different entities. ?

In JPA if i am using Generated value strategy AUTO for ids, in database level, unique values are maintained, whether GAE also follow the same? I am currently using Objectify4 for persistence.

JPA Ref : [AUTO strategy](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/generated#The_Auto_Strategy_)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your entities are of the same [kind](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Java_Kinds_and_identifiers) (= same class in JPA), then [auto-generated IDs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Java_Assigning_identifiers) are guaranteed to be unique.

**Update**: OP clarified that he needs unique IDs across different entity kinds.

You will need to use manually generated IDs - use [`allocateIds(kind, num)`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DatastoreService#allocateIds%28java.lang.String,%20long%29) method where you use a made-up `kind` for all. Use `num` of 1 to generate only one ID.

```
long uniqueId = DatastoreService.allocateIds("MyUniqueUserKind", 1).getStart().getId();
```

All IDs generated this way are always unique as long as you always use the same `kind`, in this case `"MyUniqueUserKind"`.

Comment: thanks for the replay Peter, I read that docs before posting, see my scenario: I have two different classes, say one class "Users" and another "DummyUsers" according to design, both these class should exist and they should not share same ids. because some times i use ID to identify the type of the Object. i have used Generated Value with strategy AUTO, will this satisfy my need?

Comment: No, each kind ("Users" and "DummyUsers" ) will have their own unique generator, but there is no guarantee that that they will not clash. Updated the answer with solution.

Comment: Thank you Peter,i am accepting this answer, also could you please tell me whether we can use sequence generator in gae, as we do for JPA ?

Comment: I don't know JPA  I can't say. My guess would be that JPA auto-generator under the hood uses GAE auto-generator. Which is bad news since by default this would mean that they use per-class auto generator, which wouldn't work for you as expected (= one generator for several different classes).

Comment: Thank you Peter. your answer is really helpful.

Comment: can you explain why you would need unique ids across all entities?